# R ggplot2 axis text disappears in log scale

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis-labels

I'm trying to create a plot in which one or both axes is log scale and the axis text is formatted in exponential notation as, e.g., 10^-2 but where the "-2" is superscripted.  Following examples given in Winston Chang's book and found online, I have done this successfully in the past.  However, if I use the same code that worked previously the axis text disappears.  A reproducible example:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(scales)

plot.dat <- tibble(
  time = seq(from = 0, to = 5, by = 0.2),
  C = exp(-2*time)
  )

ggplot(data = plot.dat, mapping = aes(x = time, y = C)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_y_log10(
    breaks = trans_breaks('log10', function(x) 10^x),
    labels = trans_format('log10', math_format(10^.x))
    ) +
  theme(
    axis.text.y = element_text(colour = "red", size = rel(1.5))
  )
```

Note - I added the theme statement just to be check that the text color or size wasn't getting changed for some reason.  The problem seems to be related to the `labels` line in the `scale_y_log10` part - comment that line out and axis text appears, albeit not in the desired format:
[image]
Uncomment that line and the text disappears:
[image]
This happens for `scale_x_log10` and `scale_y_log10`.  Two things make me think something has changed in `scales` but I can't seem to figure out what it is: 1) this problem happens when trying to reproduce the example (Figure 8-27) given in Chang's book, and 2) the problem occurs when using previously successful scripts.

Comment: For reference, I've tried and it's succeeded. I have `ggplot2_3.3.0` and `scales_1.1.0` installed if that's any help.

Comment: Thank you.  I had `scales` 1.0.0.  Updating solved the issue.  Sorry for missing the obvious